# CXF & Camel : IllegalArgumentException: Get the wrong parameter size to invoke the out service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, cxf, apache-camel

I recently came across this issue when trying to pass an XML to a Cxf Webservice within apache Camel.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Get the wrong parameter size to invoke the out service, Expect size 1, Parameter size 2. Please check if the message body matches the CXFEndpoint POJO Dataformat request.
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.checkParameterSize(CxfProducer.java:241)
```

One of the XML tags included a comma, which seems to be the issue.

Comment: if you have already found an answer post it, question is not enough to share info !

Comment: this is a question and answer rolled into ine.

Comment: If you are using POJO data format, you are not supposed to pass the XML yourself unless the parameter is a string which content need to be a XML.

Comment: It's my first question on stackoverflow, my bad. I tried to post the answer but I wasn't allowed to answer it myself right after I asked the question.

Comment: @WillemJiang The parameter is a string containing the XML. Should I have passed the XML in another format instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, I was passing the XML as a string in the body of the exchange. But the CxfProducer (in the POJO data format) expects a List. If it's not the case it parses the String and the comma gets interpreted as a list separator.

I hope it will help someone else as well!