# camel cxf convert comma separated string to one parameter - how to escape comma

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, cxf-client

I want to send a comma separated string to simple web service (cxf based). Without comma all works fine. Camel's type converters and magic take the string and find the only method that takes a string in wsdl and generate the xml (the wsdl has only one method at all).
If i send a comma separated string i get an error because the type converter or something else interprets the string as multiple parameters and no method matches.

Is there a way to supress or escape the ',' to let camel use it as single parameter?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is a duplicate of [how to pass String including comma in CXF service method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420522/how-to-pass-string-including-comma-in-cxf-service-method) or [CXF & Camel : IllegalArgumentException: Get the wrong parameter size to invoke the out service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032319/cxf-camel-illegalargumentexception-get-the-wrong-parameter-size-to-invoke-t?rq=1).

But if not, have you tried to encode/escape the comma in your request with a "\" before?

kind regards,
soilworker

Answer (score -2):

[how to pass String including comma in CXF service method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420522/how-to-pass-string-including-comma-in-cxf-service-method) is indeed a duplicate but with no accepted answer.
But answer number one is working, but badly explained. So we use this ugly(the list will always only have one entry) code:

Arrays.asList("my, parameter, with, commas").